# How could I convert Java code into a executable file?

Tags: java, javafx, jar, exe

How could I convert my JavaFx Code into an executable file, I have built and extracted the jar file from dist directory but there are some roots which are not containing it's External CSS files or Images.

"including JavaFx Code And Database".
Note: it's a Windows Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way would be to use a native image produced by [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org).  I believe [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com) provides services for this - specifically to target the mobile market where Apple does not allow VMs on iOS.

If you are just interested in a native launcher with a self-contained application bundle.  Use the [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) tool from the standard JDK (JDK 14 or later) to produce native application bundles that include the JVM and a regular executable launcher app.

Comment: It's a Windows Application not android or ios 

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAmir Both GraalVM and jpackage can build/package desktop applications.